# zend form validation error

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework

I was trying to validate a zend form. But problem is that in form there are three fields named country, state and city. I am sending valid data for these fields but its giving me validation error. for country, state and city only. Error messages are :

Please enter country name.
Please enter state name.
Please enter city name

Here is my form fields :

```
    $country = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('country');
    $country->setRequired(true)
            ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Country')
            ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
            ->addErrorMessage('Please enter country name.')
            ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
            ->removeDecorator('Label');

    $state = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('state');
    $state->setRequired(true)
            ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'State')
            ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
            ->addErrorMessage('Please enter state name.')
            ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
            ->addMultiOptions(array("" => "Select State"))
            ->removeDecorator('Label');

    $city = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('city');
    $city->setRequired(true)
            ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'City')
            ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
            ->addErrorMessage('Please enter city name.')
            ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
            ->addMultiOptions(array("" => "Select City"))
            ->removeDecorator('Label');
```

here is posted Data :

```
Array ( 
[full_name] => Test User 
[dob] => 2015-01-15 
[gender] => 1 
[address] => ddewewe 
[country] => DZK 
[state] => 26 
[city] => 403564 
[mobile_number] => 4535345345 
[submit] => Save )
```

Can any one help me to spot this issue?

Thanks,

M.

Comment: Please post exact error message and controller action code. So that I can help.

Comment: @Techgyani : I have added error messages to question.PLs have a look

Comment: Please share your controller code where you are handling this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you haven't set `options` for your Country, State and City drop-down list in your `Zend_form`.  You have set only one option whose value is balnk "" and you have applied validation for `required` field hence it is giving mentioned error.

You will get another error ("value was not found in the haystack" ) because your Zend Form will match the posted value in the pre specified list of a select box. Since validator will not find any such option which you're sending in `POST` data hence it will throw error.

You have following ways to resolve these issues.

1. Deactivate the validator to validate posted values in pre specified array as shown below and remove `setRequired(true)` validation:

   ```
    $country = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('country');
    $country->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Country')
    $country->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Country')
       ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
       ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
       ->removeDecorator('Label')
       ->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false); //This line will not check posted data in list
   ```
2. Set options array in your `zend_form` itself.

   ```
   class RegistrationForm extends Zend_Form {
     public function __construct($options = null) {
       $country = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('country');
       $country->setRequired(true)
           ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Country')
           ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper')
           ->addErrorMessage('Please enter country name.')
           ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
           ->removeDecorator('Label');
       foreach($options['countries'] as $option)
           $country->addMultiOption(trim($option->code),trim($option->country_name));
      }
   }
   ```

   and while creating object of Zend form in your `controller` pass array of `countries` in it.

Comment: @s-ruplali: Thnx for reply.. But i have already set all options in country state and city from controllers. That's why i am getting country, state and city in Posted Data Array.i am populating fields dynamically using jquery

Comment: So Can you please post code piece of your controller as well?

Comment: There is nothing special its like if(is valid){ save data }else{ populate form }

Comment: I wanted to see how you're setting the options for dropdowns? Through form or any other way!

Comment: from controler : setting countries $formObj->addMultiOptions(array of countries as key, value) and populating state and city via jquery

Comment: have you seen posted array data in question ??

Comment: Posted data is fine. But i would suggest you to set options in form itself as i have suggested in 2nd point in my answer. For now give it a try by using some static values only instead of foreach loop. `$country->addMultiOption("DZK" => "DZK"));` and select this option from frontend and check if it is giving error for country or not. If it works then do the same for state and city as well.

Comment: How i can do same with state and city dropdown.. I am populating state dropdown on change of country and city on change of state :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68931/discussion-between-phpfreak-and-s-rupali).